# webkit report in openerp, how to make it landscape and add a header

Tags: openerp-7

I created a web kit report file, and I am aware that it is portrait by default,
how can I make it a landscape? and add header/footer to it and how can I set that up on specific reports only?

I tried to add Web kit Headers/Footers then configure my report to
'header=True' and even try header='name_of_header_footer but it did'nt work

Answer (score 1):

You can add following code in your record for landscape,

```
        <field name="html"><![CDATA[]]></field>        
        <field name="footer_html"><![CDATA[]]></field>
        <field name="orientation">Landscape</field>
        <field name="format">Letter</field>            
        <field eval="06.0" name="margin_top"/>
        <field eval="15.0" name="margin_bottom"/>
```

and for header,

```
    <field name="html"><![CDATA[
    <html>
     your html page
    </html>
    ]]>
    </field>
```

and for footer,

```
    <field name="footer_html"><![CDATA[
    <html>
     your html page
    </html>
    ]]>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change Portrait or Landscape at `Settings > Technical > Webkit Headers/Footers`.

To change which reports use which Headers/Footers, you can go to `Settings > Technical > Actions > Reports`. Search for the desired report and change the field "Webkit Header".

Also remember that one can set the header a report should use in the XML files:

```
<report
    auto="False" 
    id="account_partner_statement" 
    model="res.partner" 
    name="account.partner_statement.webkit" 
    file="custom_reports_webkit/report/account_partner_statement.mako" 
    string="Partner Statement" 
    report_type="webkit" 
    webkit_header="custom_company_header" />
```

And one can also set the header when declaring a custom parser:

```
report_sxw.report_sxw(
    'report.account.partner_statement.webkit',
    'res.partner',
    'addons/custom_reports_webkit/report/account_partner_statement.mako',
    parser=partner_statement,
    header="custom_company_header")
```